# ios beacons monitring background

Tags: ios, objective-c, beacon

I am having problems with my app. I am using beacons but they don't seem to enterRegion when my is running in the background. The beacons arre exiting but not entering. They do enter when the app is running in the foreground. Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"BEC26202-A8D8-4A94-80FC-9AC1DE37DAA6"];
    NSString *regionIdentifier = @"us.iBeaconModules";
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID identifier:regionIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"%@",beaconUUID);

        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];


    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=YES;
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
        self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
        self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];



    return YES;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region  {
    [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLBeaconRegion *test = (CLBeaconRegion*)region;
    NSLog(@"You entered the region. %@", test.minor);
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You enterd the region."];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"Are you forgetting something?";
    notification.soundName = @"Default";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

    CLBeaconRegion *test = (CLBeaconRegion*)region;

    NSLog(@"You exited the region.%@", test.minor);
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"You exited the region. "];

}

-(void)sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = message;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if (state == CLRegionStateInside)
    {
        //Start Ranging
        [manager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    }
    else
    {
        //Stop Ranging here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add following in your plist
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
This application requires location services to work

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: just add this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions         locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];            [self.locationManagerForIbeacan setRegions:@[region]];
        
        [self.locationManagerForIbeacan startMonitoringBeacons];